# Mind numbingly confused with insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

The below code is the standard algorithm for insertion sort.

But playing around with it a bit opened my eyes to something which i cannot wrap my mind around. Any help is much appreciated.

If we replace the variable "Key" with the value arr[i] in this line

if (**key** < arr[j]), the sorting gets screwed up

can someone explain how this is working.

Thanks

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 100, 12, 31, 56, 4, 39, 2, 1 };
        int temp = 0, j, key;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            j = i - 1;
            **key = arr[i];**
            while (j >= 0) {
                if (key < arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
                j--;
            }
        }
        for (int x : arr) {
            System.out.print("[" + x + "],");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the outer loop you have

```
j = i - 1;
```

In the inner loop you have

```
arr[j + 1]
```

So, when `j = i - 1` then it is `j + 1 = i`. That means when one did not save the original `arr[i]` in `key` it is altered during the swap in the inner loop, hence the algorithm is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

This is because **(arr[i] < arr[j])** will be evaluated every time within the while loop. Since, you are shuffling the array elements within loop, **arr[i]** may change. It should be same for the all the iterations that is why it's value is set to key once outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense